# Return True ou False $.ajax().done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Olá,

Utilizando uma requsição `ajax` desta forma, eu consigo retornar true ou false.

```js
/** ## AJAX ## **/
function getAccountAjax(id, metodo) {
    let bool;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'controller/get_objeto/' + id + '/' + metodo,      
        success: (function(objeto) {        
            bool = true;
        }),
        error: (function(erro) {
            bool = false;
        })
    });
    return bool;
}
```

Mas estou utilando o ajax, conforme abaixo, porem não consigo retornar true ou false da mesma forma do exemplo acima.

Podem me ajudar ?

```js
function getAccontAjax(id, method) {
    let bool = false;
    if (responseToken != null && responseToken != '') {
        let url = 'controller/get_account?id=' + id + '&method=' + method;
        let settings = {
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            url: url,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNA==',
                'Authorizationkeyfortoken': String(responseToken),
                'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                'postman-token': '51901e9b-3613-248b-621e-ffd06d92ded4'
            },
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            statusCode: {
                401: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    location.href = base_url + 'token/logout';
                }
            }
        };
        $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
            bool = true;
        }).fail(function(e) {
            bool = false;
        });
    }
    return bool;
}
```

Comment: No segundo código vc está usando o AJAX corretamente (`async: true`). Não use AJAX síncrono. No segundo código, quando chega na linha `return bool;`, o AJAX ainda não obteve o retorno da requisição, por isso bool vai ser sempre false (`let bool = false;`). Também, usar `async: true` é redundante, porque `true` já é o valor default do `async`.

Comment: Certo, mas em situação ou como eu poderei obter o retorno como true ?

Comment: Depende mt do que vc quer fazer. O certo mesmo é chamar a função e tratar o retorno dentro do callback do `.done()` ou do `.fail()`.

Comment: estou chamando a função ajax, atraves de um botão, e se o retorno for true, eu devo abrir uma caixa de dialog modal.

`/** Crud **/
function create() {
 method = 'create'
 if (getAccontsAjax(0, method)) {
     showModal(method);
 }
}`

Comment: Por exemplo: se o AJAX falhar e cair no `.fail()`, eu faço uma coisa; se cair no `.done()`, eu faço outra, mas cada coisa dentro de cada function.

Comment: Então, vc colocaria `showModal(method);` dentro do function do `.done()`.

Comment: certo, então desnecessário um if na `function create()`
Obrigado pelas explicações..

Comment: Não é um método retornável, pois além de esperar uma promise, ele é um método encapsulado, ou seja, não há possibilidade de externar isso, mas vc pode repassar os dados ao final da promise através de um método callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `$.ajax({...})` não é retornável, pois além de esperar uma promise, ele é um método encapsulado, ou seja, não há possibilidade de externar isso, mas vc pode repassar os dados ao final da promise através de um método callback, ou através de uma ramificação de promises:

**Com callback natural:**

```
function getAccountAjax(id, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'controller/get_objeto/' + id + '/' + metodo,      
        success: (function(objeto) {        
            callback(objeto, false);
        }),
        error: (function(erro) {
           callback(erro, true);
        })
    });
}

getAccountAjax('1', function(result, error) {
   if (result.status == true && error === false) {
      //aqui retorna o true ou dados que vem da api
   }
  if (!result.status && error === false) {
      //erro interno na api
   }
  if (error === true) {
     //erro do evento ajax
     console.log(result)
   }
});
```

**Com promise:**

```
function ajax(options) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax(options).done(resolve).fail(reject);
  });
}

ajax({
  url: someURL,
  type: 'post',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    something: something,
    anotherthing: anotherthing
  })
}).then(
  function fulfillHandler(data) {
    // ...
  },
  function rejectHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // ...
  }
).catch(function errorHandler(error) {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplesmente troque a configuração async de true para false, da seguinte forma:

```js
function getAccontAjax(id, method) {
    let bool = false;
    if (responseToken != null && responseToken != '') {
        let url = 'controller/get_account?id=' + id + '&method=' + method;
        let settings = {
            async: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            url: url,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNA==',
                'Authorizationkeyfortoken': String(responseToken),
                'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                'postman-token': '51901e9b-3613-248b-621e-ffd06d92ded4'
            },
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            statusCode: {
                401: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    location.href = base_url + 'token/logout';
                }
            }
        };
        $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
            bool = true;
        }).fail(function(e) {
            bool = false;
        });
    }
    return bool;
}
```